# Beautiful-dnd rapid drag action

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm trying to build a list with folders and testcases, where the order of these can be changed. However, the folder are displayed first and the testcases second. Hence there are two droppable areas.

The functionality is working properly, but when I perform dnd actions to rapidly after eachother, then the project breaks with the following error:

```
Invariant failed: Cannot find droppable entry with id [folder1]
    at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:115106:58)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:115125:7
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:79069:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:79126:35)
    at reportUncaughtErrorInDEV (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:95067:9)
    at captureCommitPhaseError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:98731:9)
    at safelyCallDestroy (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:95152:9)
    at commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:96136:27)
    at recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:96040:9)
    at commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:96196:13)
```

This is the implementation of the two droppable fields:

```
const onDragEnd = (result) => {
  if (!result.destination) return;

  const { source, destination } = result;
  const type = result.draggableId.split('-')[1];

  if (type === FOLDER) {
    if (destination.droppableId.includes(TESTCASE)) return;

    const updatedOrder = reOrderContent(folders, source, destination);
    setFolders(updatedOrder);

    const ids = updatedOrder.map(folder => folder.id);
    const orders = updatedOrder.map(folder => folder.order);

    updateFolderOrder(ids, orders, () => {});
  } else if (type === TESTCASE) {
    if (destination.droppableId.includes(FOLDER)) return;

    const updatedOrder = reOrderContent(testcases, source, destination);
    setTestcases(updatedOrder);

    const ids = updatedOrder.map(testcase => testcase.id);
    const orders = updatedOrder.map(testcase => testcase.order);

    updateTestCaseOrder(ids, orders, () => {});

  }

  store.dispatch({ type: actions.TREE_UPDATE, payload: { name: result.draggableId } });
};
  
function reOrderContent(array, source, destination) {
  const reorderedContent = Array.from(array);
  const [movedContent] = reorderedContent.splice(source.index, 1);
  reorderedContent.splice(destination.index, 0, movedContent);
  
  return reorderedContent.map((item, index) => ({
    ...item,
    order: index,
  }));
}

function FolderContents() {
  if (!(folders ?? []).length && !(testcases ?? []).length) {
    return (
        <Box>
            {modal}
            <Card sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100%' }} style={{ padding: 80 }}>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <IconButton style={{ padding: '35px', margin: '-25px' }} onClick={() => handleOpenModal(false)}>
                        <InputIcon style={{ color: 'silver', fontSize: '120px' }} />
                    </IconButton>
                    <h2>No contents</h2>
                    <p style={{ marginTop: '0px', textAlign: 'center', color: 'gray' }}>
                        This {props.type} doesn't contain any testcases or other folders.<br />
                        You can create new resources by <b>clicking the icon</b> above.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </Card>
        </Box>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Box>
      {modal}
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'end', marginRight: '10px' }}>
          <IconButton>
              <UploadFileIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
              <PlaylistAddIcon onClick={() => handleOpenModal(true, TESTCASE)}/>
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
              <CreateNewFolderIcon onClick={() => handleOpenModal(true, FOLDER)}/>
          </IconButton>
      </div>
      <Card>
        <List>
          <Droppable droppableId={(FOLDER + object.id.toString())}>
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
              <div {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                      {folders.map((folder, index) => (
                        <Draggable draggableId={(folder.id.toString() + "-" + FOLDER)} index={index}>
                          {(provided, snapshot) => (
                            <div
                              ref={provided.innerRef}
                              {...provided.draggableProps}
                              {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                            >
                              <DirectoryNode key={(folder.id.toString() + "-" + FOLDER)} item={{ ...folder, type: FOLDER }} padding={20} type={FOLDER} display={false} />
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </Draggable>
                      ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </div>
            )}
          </Droppable>
          <Droppable droppableId={(TESTCASE + object.id.toString())}>
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
              
                <Box {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                        {testcases.map((testcase, index) => (
                          <Draggable draggableId={(testcase.id.toString() + "-" + TESTCASE)} index={index}>
                            {(provided, snapshot) => (
                              <div
                                ref={provided.innerRef}
                                {...provided.draggableProps}
                                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                              >
                                <DirectoryNode key={(testcase.id.toString() + "-" + TESTCASE)} item={{ ...testcase, type: TESTCASE }} padding={20} type={TESTCASE} display={false} />
                              </div>
                            )}
                          </Draggable>
                        ))}
                  {provided.placeholder}
                </Box>
              )}
            </Droppable>
        </List>
      </Card>
    </Box>
  );
}

return (
  <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
    <FolderContents />
  </DragDropContext>
);
```

Has anyone any idea as to how to fix this error, or perhaps build in a timeout where the dnd functionality is disabled?